# Where's The Scanned Image?

Tags: hp, gimp, scanning

- Ubuntu 13.04
- Gimp 2.8.4
- HP OfficeJet 6600 scanner/printer
- hplip 3.12.11 (drivers & stuff for the HP scanner/printer)

When I scan in GIMP (file->scan...), it gives me a "scan successful" message after a couple minutes. The scanner/printer also displays that the scan was successful on it's little screen. No error messages or anything like that.

Problem is... the scanned image doesn't automatically display in GIMP once it's scanned. So I'm guessing that it's scanned elsewhere or something? Am I just missing a step or if the scanned image actually scanned to a file that I have to open in GIMP? Or am I going about this all wrong? I've never scanned via Linux before.

Comment: Have you checked the Pictures folder?

Comment: If you install and use **XSane** instead you can specify a default path as well as saving scanned images anywhere you like manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in your pictures folder. Alternatively, you could use 'Simple Scan' (comes with Ubuntu) instead of GIMP.